# Create a new zoo object based on a vector of variable names

Tags: r, get, lag, zoo

Set seed and variables. Please assume all everything is this 
section is given and unalterable.

```
library(zoo)
set.seed(123)
a <- zoo(rnorm(10), order.by = as.Date(50:60))
b <- zoo(rnorm(10), order.by = as.Date(50:60))
c <- zoo(rnorm(10), order.by = as.Date(50:60))
lags <- c(1,3,1)
variables <- c("a","c","b")
```

I want to create an adequate zoo object that picks variables from the list "variables" in that order and applies lags from "lags". This is my desired output (including column names):

```
                   a.l1       c.l3        b.l1
20/02/1970           NA         NA          NA
21/02/1970  -0.56047565         NA   1.2240818
22/02/1970  -0.23017749         NA   0.3598138
23/02/1970   1.55870831 -1.0678237   0.4007715
24/02/1970   0.07050839 -0.2179749   0.1106827
25/02/1970   0.12928774 -1.0260044  -0.5558411
26/02/1970   1.71506499 -0.7288912   1.7869131
27/02/1970   0.46091621 -0.6250393   0.4978505
28/02/1970  -1.26506123 -1.6866933  -1.9666172
01/03/1970  -0.68685285   0.837787   0.7013559
02/03/1970  -0.44566197  0.1533731  -0.4727914
```

This is one the closest I could get to, but it doesn't work. The problem is somewhere in the "get" function I think.

```
lag(as.zoo(mget(variables)),lags-1)
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mget(variables)` is actually returning a list with one element per variable in `variables`, containing the vector of values in that variable.

You can get it into a structure usable by `lag()` by binding the elements of the list into columns using `do.call("cbind", mget(variables))`. As far as I know, it's actually unnecessary to wrap this in `as.zoo()`.

To get the proper lags, you need `-lags` rather than `lags-1`.

Putting this together, you get:

```
lagged <- lag(do.call("cbind", mget(variables)), -lags)
```

That contains the 1 and 3 lags for each variable, so you'll have to do a bit of post-processing to get the format you want. The following should do it:

```
lagged <- lagged[, c("a.lag-1", "c.lag-3", "b.lag-1")]
colnames(lagged) <- c("a.l1", "c.l3", "b.l1")
```

Note though that since at 1970-02-20 all lags are `NA`, this row is excluded from the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be easily handled by cbinding the zoo data as data.frame and then applying `mutate` from `dplyr` and then saving the data as zoo.

```
#cbind and apply mutate
x1<-data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
x1$Date<-row.names(x1)
x2<-x1 %>%
mutate(a=lag(a,1),b=lag(b,3),c=lag(c,1))
#convert back to zoo object
x3<-zoo(x2,as.Date(x2$Date))
x3$Date<-NULL

head(x3)
           a           b          c         
1970-02-20 <NA>        <NA>       <NA>      
1970-02-21 -0.56047565 <NA>       -1.0678237
1970-02-22 -0.23017749 <NA>       -0.2179749
1970-02-23  1.55870831  1.2240818 -1.0260044
1970-02-24  0.07050839  0.3598138 -0.7288912
1970-02-25  0.12928774  0.4007715 -0.6250393
```